# Clojure update-in on two keys and two functions

Tags: clojure

I am trying to update a nested hashmap using `update-in` function. But I want to update value of two keys, using differents functions. For exemple:

I have this hash:

```
{:1 {:value 0, :active false}, :2 {:value 0, :active false}
```

And I want update the key :1 to:

```
{:1 {:value 2, :active true}, :2 {:value 0, :active false}
```

There is some way to do this ?

Thanks in advance

**Update**
Maybe I just can use `assoc`: `(assoc my-map :1 {:value 2, :active true})`

Comment: `:1` and `:2` are weird keywords, why not just the numbers `1` and `2` as keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have more than one k/v pair with assoc:

```
user=> (def m {:1 {:value 0, :active false}, :2 {:value 0, :active false}})
#'user/m
user=> (update-in m [:1] assoc :value 1 :active true)
{:1 {:value 1, :active true}, :2 {:value 0, :active false}}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are also `assoc-in` which works like `assoc`. The only difference is, that you provide a vector of keys instead of a single key. So maybe you can pipe your map through some `assoc-in`'s.

Or you use the function `update` (added in 1.7):

```
(update {:1 {:value 0, :active false}, :2 {:value 0, :active false}
    :1 (fn [{:keys [value active]]
           (magic value active)))
```